# Running protractor tests on IE 11

Tags: linux, windows, protractor, internet-explorer-11

OK, so I have been searching a lot to get proper solution to the blocker I am facing right now.  Let me give you a background of what I have done so far :

I want to run protractor tests (located on Linux machine) on IE 11 of Windows Server 2012 R2 (IP : 10.81.73.248). My protractorTest.conf.js has below :

*exports.config = {
 seleniumAddress: 'http://10.81.73.248:4444/wd/hub',
 baseURL: 'http://10.81.78.137:80000/',
 capabilities: {
 browserName: 'internet explorer',
 platform: 'ANY',
 version: '11'
},*

On my Windows Server 2012 R2 machine, I've downloaded *IEDriverServer_Win32_2.47.0* and placed it under *C:\Windows\System32*, environment variable PATH has been updated with above location. Protected mode settings are same for all zones. Windows machine also has *selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar* placed under *C:\Users\Selenium*.

On Windows machine, I am starting selenium server using below command :

*java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -port 4444 -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\Windows\System32\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.47.0\IEDriverServer.exe"* , which starts selenium server fine.

With above settings, I run protractor tests from my Linux machine using *grunt protractor_test*, which launches IE browser on Windows machine, shows *localhost:dynamic port* and a message as : *This is the initial page of webdriver server* and within 2 seconds, closes the browser.

The exception I get on selenium server terminal is as below :

*Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit() ?*

This is where I am stuck at. I looked at various posts which describes similar issue (?) as mine along with the potential solution, but I am unable to resolve my issue here.

Is there anything I might be doing wrong to setup the connections ? or am I missing some steps to get me through ?

I would really appreciate if you guide me in resolving this long time pending blocker.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to run using old selenium version.It should be 2.53.x something.

Few basics things to check first regarding IE execution:

1).IE Setting for protractor(Selenium)
http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/

2).Take IE driver of 32 bit(don't take 64 it has known slowness issues) and manually copy on the following path:

Root Folder\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1

3). IE Driver can be downloaded from following path:
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.53/

```
                             **OR**
```

Please upgrade your protractor version to latest like 4.0.11 by changing the version in package.json file and do from command prompt(inside project root directory):

```
npm update
```

and then give update your selenium driver with following command from command prompt

```
webdriver-manager update --ie
```

it will update the selenium version of IE driver to latest and then try running your tests again.

Comment: webdriver-manager update --ie will download 64 bit ieDriver
webdriver-manager update --ie32 will download 32 bit ieDriver